# How do I encode an array as a value of a JSON field?

Tags: json, go

I just started learning golang, and I had a question: how can I put an array into an object (struct) so that when parsed in json it looks like this:

```
{
"key":"value",
"array": [1, 2, 3, "num", null]
}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang

Answer (score 1):

Just create a struct with the appropriate data types and unmarshal into it:

https://play.golang.org/p/CLMaN9ikBQS

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Key string `json:"key"`
    Array []interface{} `json:"array"`
}
byt := []byte(`{
    "key":"value",
    "array": [1, 2, 3, "num", null]
}`)
dat := MyStruct{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(dat)
```